# Perl: Is there a way to use a hashref as a for-loop iteration variable?

Tags: perl, loops

You can do something like:

```
my $hr = {start=>3, end=>20};
for my $i ($hr->{start}..$hr->{end}){
   ... 
}
```

But what if you don't want `$i` and instead want to use and increment the `$hr->{start}` value? The following won't work:

```
for $hr->{start} ($hr->{start}..$hr->{end}){
   ... 
}
```

---

#### Alternatives:

1. The following is one way to handle it, but is there a way to include the incrementation with the iteration variables?

   ```
   for ($hr->{start}..$hr->{end}){
      ... 
      $hr->{start}++;
   }
   ```
2. Another way using a c-for-loop:

   ```
   for ( ; $hr->{start} <= $hr->{end} ; $hr->{start}++){
      ... 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Perl-style `for/foreach VAR (LIST)` construction won't do what you want. The index variable must be a simple scalar. More importantly, the index variable is always localized and aliased to the items in the `LIST`, and its meaning is lost outside the `foreach` loop.

```
my $foo = 42;
for $foo (1..10) {
   ...
}
print $foo;      # 42
```

But within a C-style `for` loop you can do anything you want with the expressions.

```
$hr = { start => 1 , end => 10 };
for ( ; $hr->{start} <= $hr->{end} ; $hr->{start}++ ) {
    ...
}
print $hr->{start};       # now it is 11
```

Comment: I see you updated your question to include the C-style loop 28 seconds before I submitted this answer.

Comment: I see you posted the same basic explanation as I did a few seconds before me, so his update's fair. :)

Answer (score 3):

Increment at end of loop:

```
for (; $hr->{start} <= $hr->{end}; ++$hr->{start}) {
   ... 
}
```

Increment at start of loop:

```
while ($hr->{start}++ <= $hr->{end}) {
   ... 
}
```

Comment: ahh a `while` loop, d'oh.  haven't used one of those in perl for simple incrementation iterations in a while (pun).

Comment: every while loop can be written as an equivalent C-style for loop, and vice versa

Comment: @mob, yes, but one form is usually simpler than the other. I picked the simpler form in both cases. The question was about style, after all.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could always:

```
for ($hr->{start}..$hr->{end}){
  $hr->{start} = $_;
  ...
}
```

Basically, if you don't stick a "my" in front of the variable, perl sticks an implicit "local" in front of the loop variable.  And since you can't localize a reference (that wouldn't make any sense, if you think about it), you can't use a reference as the iterator.